# How to match vector elements as a whole

Tags: r, match

I would like to know the way to match the vector as a whole. I have two vectors `a,b`

```
a <- c(5,1,2,6,3,4,8)
b <- c(1,2,3)
```

I know a few ways to match the vector elements like

```
 match(b,a)
#[1] 2 3 5

b%in%a
#[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

On `match()` i get the location of individual vector elements and for `%in%` i get logical for individual vector elements. But I am looking to match the whole vector `b` with `a` at once. It should not match the individual elements but the whole vector and get the location where the match starts.

**Desired output:**

In the above vectors match is not found because I am looking for the whole vector not the individual vector items.

Comment: @Henrik. Thanks for finding a possible duplicate. I'l have a look, may be helpful.

Comment: @rawr Thanks for guiding to the link. The question is already closed and link provided seem not related. The link provided by `Henrik` earlier, later deleted works good. Thanks all!!

Comment: @rawr !!. I am referring to the link at the top not your link. Pls don't delete the link.

Comment: Looks like there is some confusion with the link.  I will reopen and @rawr can dupe it with his link

Answer (score 1):

How about if we check the length (with `na.omit`) of the output of `match()` against the vector we are testing

```
ifelse(length(na.omit(match(b, a))) == length(b), match(b, a)[1], NA)
#[1] 2
#adding a new value in b so it wont match, we get
b  <- c(1, 2, 3, 9)
ifelse(length(na.omit(match(b, a))) == length(b), match(b, a)[1], NA)
#[1] NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always brute force this, just loop through the vectors element by element.

```
a <- c(5,1,2,6,3,4,8)
b <- c(1,2,3)

matchr <- function(a,b){

    # First, loop through the a vector
    for(i in 1:(length(a)-length(b))){

        pos <- FALSE

        # Next loop through the b vector, 
        for(j in 1:length(b)){

            # as we're looping through b, check if each element matches the corresponding part of the a vector we're currently at.
            if( a[i+j-1] == b[j]){
                pos <- TRUE
            } else{
                pos <- FALSE
                break
            }
        }

        # if all the elements match, return where we are in the a vector
        if(pos == TRUE){
            return(i)
        } 
    }
    # if we finish the a vector and never got a match, return no match.
    return("No match")
}

matchr(a,b)
[1] "No match"

d <- c(7,5,4,2,1,2,3,8,5)

matchr(d,b)
[1] 5

e <- c(2,3,8)

matchr(d,e)
[1] 6
```

If your real vector is much larger, you may consider compiling the function via `matchr <- compiler::cmpfun(matchr)` or rewriting it with Rcpp.

Edit: Another way

Make a list with your `a` vector split into `length(b)` sized vectors, then test if `list(b)` is in the split up `a` list:

```
matchr2 <- function(a){
    m <- list()
    for(i in 1:(length(a)-length(b))){
        m[[i]] <- c( a[i : (length(b) + i - 1)] ) 
    }
    m
}

mlist <- matchr2(a)

list(b) %in% mlist
[1] FALSE

mlist <- matchr2(d)

list(b) %in% mlist
[1] TRUE
```

Again, you'll get significant speed benefits by compiling the function.

Answer (score 0):

An approach, with a couple of examples:

```
wholematch<-function(a=c(5,1,3,2,1,2,5,6,2,6),b=c(1,2,6))
{
    for(loop.a in 1:(length(a)-length(b)))
    {
    #pmatch gives the first occurrence of each value of b in a. To be sure of finding the consecutive matches, use pmatch starting from all the possible positions of "a"
    wmatch<-(loop.a-1)+pmatch(b,a[loop.a:length(a)])
    #If at any time the number of matches is less than the length of the vector to match, we will never find a match. Return NA 
    if(length(na.omit(pmatch(b,a[loop.a:length(a)])))<length(b)) return(NA)
    #If all indices are adjacent, return the vector of indices
    if(max(diff(wmatch))==1) return(wmatch) #return(wmatch[1]) if you only want the start
    }
}

wholematch()
[1] NA

wholematch(a=c(5,1,3,2,1,2,5,6,2,6),b=c(6,2,6))
[1]  8  9 10
```